# Can I use as one of variables weighted average of a few market indexes for time series?

Tags: time-series, index-decomposition

Can I use as one of variables weighted average of a few market indexes for time series?
I saw it in one of the thesis i read recently, but i didn't see people commonly doing it in academic literature.